# Can someone translate Shomo VaTismach into English?

Tags: shabbat, translation

Can someone please provide or direct me to an English translation of this liturgical song?
As sung here by my cousin the Chasan, Moshe Korn

https://youtu.be/d9fgwtxnfgQ

I don't speak hebrew and cannot find a translation anywhere.
Many thanks

Comment: Hi It's the last few lines of psalm 97

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Miriam and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.97.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%A9%D7%81%D6%B8%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%A2%D6%B8%D6%AC%D7%94%20%D7%95%D6%B7%D7%AA%D6%BC%D6%B4%D7%A9%D7%82%D6%B0%D7%9E%D6%B7%D6%A8%D7%97%E2%80%89%D7%80,hearing%20it%2C%20rejoices%2C) a link straight to the translation for you.